# Generating JQuery from C# (MVC 5 - Razor)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor, code-generation

I have generated some jQuery from C#/Razor. Before writing the code to generate the jQuery I wrote a static version of the jQuery that I needed to mimic with the code I would be generating from the Razor (C#) syntax.

Mission accomplished. After writing the Razor code using C# code blacks I was able to generate a block of jQuery that was verbatim exactly the same as the working static version of the jQuery.

PROBLEM: WHen I load the page the jQUery doesn't work, but when I view source. the jQuery is perfect???

Is there a reason that jQuery generated by Razor would not work even though the JS in generates is perfectly formatted jQuery?

I can provide code samples but the reality is that my HTML page that is generated is perfect. But only the jQuery in the block I generated from Razor is not working???

**static jQuery:**

```
<script>
 $('#centerview').on('click', function () {
     var $$ = $(this)
     if (!$$.is('.imageChecked')) {
         $$.addClass('imageChecked');
         $('#2').prop('checked', true);
     } else {
         $$.removeClass('imageChecked');
         $('#2').prop('checked', false);
     }
 });
 $('#balconyview').on('click', function () {
     var $$ = $(this)
     if (!$$.is('.imageChecked')) {
         $$.addClass('imageChecked');
         $('#3').prop('checked', true);
     } else {
         $$.removeClass('imageChecked');
         $('#3').prop('checked', false);
     }
 });
</script>
```

**Razor code that generates jQuery**

```
@{
    var jqCounter = 1;
}
@foreach (var img in Model.Render.Images)
{
    var imgName = img.Name.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
    @:$('#@imgName').on('click', function () {
        @:var $$ = $(this)
        @:if (!$$.is('.imageChecked')) {
            @:$$.addClass('imageChecked');
            @:$('#@jqCounter').prop('checked', true);
        @:} else {
            @:$$.removeClass('imageChecked');
            @:$('#@jqCounter').prop('checked', false);
    @:});
    jqCounter++;
}
```

**HTML Copied directly from pages final outpu**t

```
<script>
    $('#straightonviewz').on('click', function () {
        var $$ = $(this)
        if (!$$.is('.imageChecked')) {
        $$.addClass('imageChecked');
        $('#1').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $$.removeClass('imageChecked');
        $('#1').prop('checked', false);
    });
    $('#centerview').on('click', function () {
        var $$ = $(this)
        if (!$$.is('.imageChecked')) {
        $$.addClass('imageChecked');
        $('#2').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $$.removeClass('imageChecked');
        $('#2').prop('checked', false);
    });
    $('#balconyview').on('click', function () {
        var $$ = $(this)
        if (!$$.is('.imageChecked')) {
        $$.addClass('imageChecked');
        $('#3').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $$.removeClass('imageChecked');
        $('#3').prop('checked', false);
    });
</script>
```

It's perfect? is there a reason why code generated from C# would not work? Is it a server/Compile time thing? I have never tried to generate JavaScript from C#/Razor code before??

I do get an error on the HTML page right before the line
     $('#balconyview').on('click', function () {

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: Yes, when I generate the jQuery by using Razor I get 1 error on the  line directly before ` $('#balconyview').on('click', function () {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason why javascript defined through razor should not work on a browser. The only reason is syntax errors which exactly your case...

First, You've got a low unclosed parenthesis and curly brackets

Then, You've got undefined tokens here...

```
else {
    $$.removeClass('imageChecked');
    $('#1').prop('checked', false);
});
```

`$$` is not defined in the `else` block...it is rather defined in the `if` block and it goes out of scope as soon as it hits the `else` block

#### Solution

To fix the sytanx errors you have introduced, close the parenthesis and curly brackets and make the `$$` variable accessible to the `else` block...

```
@{
    var jqCounter = 1;
}
@foreach (var img in Model.Render.Images)
{
    var imgName = img.Name.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
    @:$('#@imgName').on('click', function () {
        @:var $$ = $(this);
        @:if (!$$.is('.imageChecked')) {
            @:$$.addClass('imageChecked');
            @:$('#@jqCounter').prop('checked', true);
        @:} else {
            @:$$.removeClass('imageChecked');
            @:$('#@jqCounter').prop('checked', false);
    @:}});
    jqCounter++;
}
```

#### Update

Actually, I think I got a bit dizzy reading the code, the `$$` variable is perfectly in scope....just close the `else` block

Comment: Ahh, Let me try to fix this and see if I can get that resolved.

Comment: Dangit. I wasn't closing my elses.. Right?

Comment: It's so late and I have been working for 10 hours. One curly brace was overlooked. lol I appreciate the second pair of eyes, even with the error in the console pinpointing it I just wasn't seeing it. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Sorry I made you dizzy? That is why I provided the HTML output. But I'm grateful for the help! These are the problems that grid you to a halt at 2am in the morning.. THanks again!

Comment: @EricB it's alright mate. It's not your fault. I was a bit overloaded here. Cheers